# The text on the cell to be able to see after clicking

Tags: ios, objective-c

**The text on the cell to be able to see after clicking**

code for **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DrawConfirmCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    if (cell ==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }


    Model *model = [_itemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = model.sign;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = model.message;
    [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:model.fontSize.intValue]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Explain your question better. What you want to do?

Comment: What is your question? You've just posted code.

Comment: @zz2370092729, I think you are not seeing label after clicking on cell. You might not because you have selected cell. Put following code in your tables didSelectRowAtIndex method and check.    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

Comment: My assignment to detailTextLabel.text text, but did not display, must click on cell can see. Add: text color and highlight color is not the same, because I will text set into red will happen

Comment: I found the reason, set the font to cell.detailTextLabel, model.fontSize to nil, this is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, You are not seeing text after clicking on Cell.
Reason is your text color is gray and so selected cell background color.

If you want to able to select cell for any operation on that, than you need to change your text color.

If you don't want to make it selection visible, you can remove selection of that selected cell by following method.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```